# VCL C++ (Brush border while drawing)

Tags: c++, drawing, border, vcl

Could someone help me. I am drawing a arrow by using polygon, one for square and one for triangle.

```
image->Canvas->Brush->Color = clGreen;
image->Canvas->Polygon(s, 5);
image->Canvas->Brush->Color = clGreen;
image->Canvas->Polygon(t, 4);
```

Problem is that black little gap between them. I am sure there is no problem with coordinates because when i draw two ellipses one in another problem appears again as tiny black border.

Comment: What are the actual values of `s` and `t`? Can you provide a screenshot of the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas->Polygon()` draws a series of lines using `Canvas->Pen` and then fills the shape using `Canvas->Brush`.  If you do not want the lines to appear, set `Canvas->Pen->Width` to 0, or set `Canvas->Pen->Style` to `psClear`.